# Activity Recognition not work after "wifi & mobile network location" is turn off and turn on

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I'm using Activity recognition to detecting user activity.

I found a strange behavior, after I turn off and turn on "WiFi & mobile network location" the application did not get any activity recognition updates.

After restarting the phone, the application is getting update from Google play services until I turn off "WiFi & mobile network location" once again.

Is there any known issue with Activity recognition on Google play services when "WiFi & mobile network location" is turned off and on again?.

Comment: I'm facing same issue....

Comment: Hey i too have come across a lot of issues with activity recognition. I observed that if the location services from Wifi and mobile tower are turned off ,the play library fail to give user activity updates. Sometimes it happens if the mock locxations are enabled.
This seems to be another issue.I have tested the same and it is happening for me too. :(:(.I have tried it on a couple of devices and this issue seems to be consistent

Comment: I am having the same issue with requesting for periodic updates. It is happening only with their latest google services update from 16th of January! they ruined the location service with their suppose battery life improvement!

Comment: yes i got the issue after Google play service update.Is any way to handle it?

Comment: This issue happens only with the latest version Google play services. I cross checked it by uninstalling the play services update. After that the issue was not present in Google play service version 3.2. Looks like the Play service update has introduced some issues.

Comment: This issue is fixed in latest update of Google Play services(4.3.23 (1069729-030)). All we need to do is replace library project "google-play-services_lib" with latest version(4.3.23 (1069729-030)). I noticed a delay of about 1 minute in AR updates if we toggle location settings, but it works.