# Network Provider failed after turning off Wifi & mobile network location

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I'm using fused location provider to get user location in my application. I connect to Wifi and get user location via network provider, I can't use gps provider since I am in a building.

When I turn off and on the "wifi & mobile network location" in setting, my onLocationChanged never get call afterwards and maps won't show the small blue dot which indicating my location. I have to restart my phone to get it work again. Same behavior occur when I turn off and on the setting.

I am currently using google play service revision 14. Tested on nexus 4.

Similar problem exist in this link which also rely on google play service.

[Activity Recognition not work after "wifi & mobile network location" is turn off and turn on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228378/activity-recognition-not-work-after-wifi-mobile-network-location-is-turn-off)

Answer (score -2):

```
try to use GPSProvider to get accurate location
```